# Windows Server 2008 R2 takes too long to start in esxi 5.5 after converting the Physical Machine into Virtual machine with P2V Software

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi

I converted the Windows Server 2008 R2 which is installed on the Physical Server into virtual machine with P2V software. I installed this Virtual machine in Vmware ESXI 5.5. This guest OS takes too long to Start (before login scree appearance) in Virtual machine. I am using Hardware of HP G6 Server.
**Resources Allocated to VM**
CPU core =1
Ram  =4GB
Virtulization Software = ESXI 5.5
Guest OS = Windows Server 2008 R2

**Steps taken for remedy**
1) update my firmware.
2) remove unavailable hardware drivers from device manager.

Please find below images for resource utilization of VM.
[DataStore Utitlization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loYWp.jpg)
[CPU Utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBYUA.jpg)
[Disk Utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHmHQ.jpg)
[Ram Utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRdh9.jpg)

Please find below link for log file of VMware.
[Log File of VMWare](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tWarmJyIocenJ0fdieE2slrY75WZgI1e)

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Why so much out of date software?

Comment: `This guest OS takes too long to Start` - How long is too long?

Comment: @joeqwerty it takes about 10 to 15 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's on a domain controller when I remove it from the domain and join this to WorkGroup then this issue has been resolved.